# Type parameter of the predict() function

Tags: r

What is the difference between `type="class"` and `type="response"` in the `predict` function?

For instance between:

```
predict(modelName, newdata=testData, type = "class")
```

and

```
predict(modelName, newdata=testData, type = "response")
```

Comment: Which `predict` function? `predict` is a generic function for predictions from the results of various model fitting functions. The function invokes particular methods which depend on the class of the first argument.

Answer (score 14):

Response gives you the numerical result while class gives you the label assigned to that value.

Response lets you to determine your threshold. For instance,

```
glm.fit = glm(Direction~., data=data, family = binomial, subset = train)
glm.probs = predict(glm.fit, test, type = "response")
```

In `glm.probs` we have some numerical values between 0 and 1. Now we can determine the threshold value, let's say 0.6. Direction has two possible outcomes, up or down.

```
glm.pred = rep("Down",length(test))
glm.pred[glm.probs>.6] = "Up"
```

Answer (score 9):

`type = "response"` is used in **glm** models and `type = "class"` is used in **rpart** models(CART).
See:

- [predict.glm](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html)
- [predict.rpart](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/rpart/html/predict.rpart.html)

Answer (score 4):

see `?predict.lm`:
`predict.lm` produces a vector of predictions or a matrix of predictions and bounds with column names `fit`, `lwr`, and `upr` if interval is set. For `type = "terms"` this is a matrix with a column per term and may have an attribute "constant".

```
> d <- data.frame(x1=1:10,x2=rep(1:5,each=2),y=1:10+rnorm(10)+rep(1:5,each=2))
> l <- lm(y~x1+x2,d)
> predict(l)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
 2.254772  3.811761  4.959634  6.516623  7.664497  9.221486 10.369359 11.926348 13.074222 14.631211 

> predict(l,type="terms")
           x1         x2
1  -7.0064511  0.8182315
2  -5.4494620  0.8182315
3  -3.8924728  0.4091157
4  -2.3354837  0.4091157
5  -0.7784946  0.0000000
6   0.7784946  0.0000000
7   2.3354837 -0.4091157
8   3.8924728 -0.4091157
9   5.4494620 -0.8182315
10  7.0064511 -0.8182315
attr(,"constant")
[1] 8.442991
```

i.e. `predict(l)` is the row sums of `predict(l,type="terms")` + the constant

Comment: You're referring to the linear model right? (predict.lm) but as far I know, type class and type response is related to the Classification models. Would you explain about these parameter values?

Comment: See shadow's comment - I thought that modelName was most likely to be an lm object, but if not you'll need to tell us what class(ModelName) gives, or look at the helpfile for predict.class().

Comment: Thanks for your response, got the answer in ?predict.glm and ?predict.rpart. I totally ignored the genericity treating them like overloaded methods.