# Using predict function on binomial GLMM: producing a numerical not binomial value

Tags: r, predict, mixed-models, binomial-coefficients

I have been running a GLMM using the glmmTMB package on a large dataset. Example data below

```
structure(list(code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2388", 
"2390", "12950", "12952", "12954", "12956", "12958", "12960", 
"12962", "12964", "12966", "12968", "13573", "13574", "13575", 
"13576", "13577", "14203", "19318", "19319", "19320", "19321", 
"19322", "19515", "19517", "19523", "19524", "25534", "25535", 
"25536", "25537", "25539", "25540", "25541", "25542", "25543", 
"25544", "25545", "25546", "25547", "25548", "25549", "25550", 
"25552", "25553", "27583", "27584", "27585", "27586", "27588", 
"27589", "27590", "27591", "27592", "27593", "27594", "27595", 
"27596", "27597", "27598", "27599", "27600", "27601", "27602", 
"27603", "27604", "27605", "27606", "27607", "27608", "27609", 
"27610", "27611", "27613", "27614", "27615", "27616", "27617", 
"27618", "27619", "27620", "27621", "27622", "27624", "27625", 
"27626", "27627", "27629", "27630", "27631", "27632", "34176", 
"34177", "34178", "34179", "52975", "52977", "52978", "54814", 
"54815", "54816", "54817", "54821", "54822", "54823", "54824", 
"54825", "54835", "54837", "54838", "54839", "54840", "54841", 
"54842", "54843", "54844", "54845", "54846", "54847", "54848", 
"54849", "54851", "54852", "54853", "54856", "54858", "54859", 
"54860", "54863", "54864", "54866", "54869", "54872", "54873", 
"54874", "54875", "54876", "54877", "54878", "54880", "54882", 
"54883", "54884", "54886", "54887", "54889", "54890", "54892", 
"54893", "54895", "54896", "54898", "54899", "54900", "54901", 
"54903", "54904", "54905", "54906", "54911", "54912", "54914", 
"54915", "54931", "54933", "54934", "54935", "54937", "54939", 
"54940", "54941", "54942", "54943", "54944", "54945", "54946", 
"54947", "54948", "54950", "54952", "54954", "54955", "54957", 
"54958", "54959", "54961", "54962"), class = "factor"), station = 
c("PB14", 
"PB14", "PB16", "PB16"), species = c("Silvertip Shark", "Silvertip Shark", 
"Silvertip Shark", "Silvertip Shark"), sex = c("F", "F", "F", 
"F"), size = c(112, 112, 112, 112), datetime = c("1466247120", 
"1466247420", "1467026100", "1469621400"), year = c("2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016"), month = c(6, 6, 6, 7), hour = c("11", "11", 
"12", "13"), season = c("dry season", "dry season", "dry season", 
"dry season"), daynight = c("day", "day", "day", "day"), time_diff = c(4, 
5, 5821, 43255), offshore = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = 
c("offshore", 
"onshore"), class = "factor"), rowN = 1:4), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm looking to run the model on 80% of my data then validate it using the predict() function. Using the code below

```
Off_80 <- Off %>% sample_frac(.80)

Off_20  <- anti_join(Off, Off_80, by = 'rowN')

OffMod_80 <- glmmTMB(offshore ~ sex + log(size) + species*daynight + species*season + (1|code), family=binomial(), data=Off_80)

pred_Off20 <- as.data.frame(predict(OffMod_80, newdata=Off_20, type="response", allow.new.levels=TRUE))
```

The idea being I would then compare the predicted results to my observed results to validate the strength of the model.

However using this rather than getting a 'offshore' or 'onshore' response, I get a numerical value.

```
         predict()
     1   0.2807461                                                                     
     2   0.2631816                                                                       
     3   0.2631816                                                                     
     4   0.2807461
```

Is there anyway to get the predict function to spit out a binomial response? Or how do I interpret these values as binomial?

Initially I had my response variable as a 1 or a 0, but following this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139978/i-was-expecting-0-and-1-as-an-answer-of-a-predict-function-in-r) I changed the values to factors. But still predict() spits out a numerical value.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict()` for binomial models returns the *probability* of a success or failure, it does not return 1 or 0 (because you can predict that outcome only with a certain *probability*). So if you want to check your model performance, you can try to calculate the *area under curve*:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(pROC)

data(mtcars)
n <- nrow(mtcars)
train <- sample(1:n, n * .8, TRUE)
mtcars_train <- mtcars[train, ]
mtcars_test <- mtcars[-train, ]

m <- glmmTMB(formula = vs ~ hp + wt + (1 | gear), family = binomial, data = mtcars_train)
p <- predict(m, newdata = mtcars_test)

auc(roc(response = mtcars_test$vs, predictor = p))
#> Area under the curve: 0.9107
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Another way is to compare the percentage of correct predictions (PCP) of the full model with the null model (see *Herron, M. (1999). Postestimation Uncertainty in Limited Dependent Variable Models. Political Analysis, 8, 83–98*). Here, the PCP of the full model should be remarkably higher:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(insight)

data(mtcars)

m <- glmmTMB(formula = vs ~ hp + wt + (1 | gear), family = binomial, data = mtcars)
m0 <- glmmTMB(formula = vs ~ 1 + (1 | gear), family = binomial, data = mtcars)

y <- insight::get_response(m)
y0 <- insight::get_response(m0)

n <- nobs(m)
n0 <- nobs(m0)

p <- predict(m, type = "response")
p0 <- predict(m0, type = "response")

pcp_full <- (sum(1 - p[y == 0]) + sum(p[y == 1])) / n
pcp_null <- (sum(1 - p0[y0 == 0]) + sum(p0[y0 == 1])) / n0

# percentage correct predictions full model
pcp_full
#> [1] 0.8374718

# percentage correct predictions null model
pcp_null
#> [1] 0.6614221
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Finally, if you really want something like `0` and `1`, you can use `simulate()`, which returns values on the same scale as the original response. Than you can compare how many of the simulated responses match the actual response:

```r
library(glmmTMB)

data(mtcars)

m <- glmmTMB(formula = vs ~ hp + wt + (1 | gear), family = binomial, data = mtcars)

# simulate response, first column = successes
s <- simulate(m)$sim_1[, 1]

# proportion of response values that equal simulated responses
mean(mtcars$vs == s)
#> [1] 0.875
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes just chasing up auc seems the best method, thanks for answering and giving multiple option that's great

Answer (score 0):

The predict function is giving you the probability that the Offshore variable is "Offshore" given the predictors you provided in the model for the values expressed in the test dataset. You might want to look at the answers to this question: [Type parameter of the predict() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085096/type-parameter-of-the-predict-function). Where they highlight the difference between ?predict.glm and ?predict.rpart. I can not replicate your analysis from the data you provided but look at the simple example from: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-glm1/. This shows how glm works (in general) and what the predict.glm function is giving you. I hope that helps.